# How to automatically include Qt Linguist files into Qt resources for the CMake project?

Tags: qt, cmake, resources, qt5, translation

I use CMake to build Qt project with internatiolization support. Using `qt5_create_translation` I can create `*.ts` files into the source directory and `*.qm` files into the build directory.

I want to reduce the number of files I should to distribute. Storing translation files `:/translations/*.qm` into the Qt resources is straitforward solution.

But during build process names of the resources are generated automatically and there is no native way to emplace them into the `*.qrc` file automatically.

How to achieve desired using, say, `add_custom_command` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Qt's qrc file is just xml files. Thus you can an external tool to add it.

A pure cmake solution could be:

1. Create a dummy resource file named `@TRANS_FILE@`
2. Add this file to your `qrc` file
3. Fetch the name of the translation file into a variable. Don't know how.
4. Use cmake's `configure_file` to replace the dummy resource name

Example:

```
set(TRANS_FILE ${NameOfTranslationFile})
configure_file(infile.qrc outfile.qrc @ONLY)
```